# phpMyAdmin versión 4.7.7

Tags: phpmyadmin

Veran, recientemente he actualizado a la versión 4.7.7 de phpMyAdmin.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ello, la carpeta que tengo marcada con el ratón la he borrado y he puesto en su lugar la nueva versión.
Y ahora me encuentro con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me pide un usuario y contraseña, pero no se cuales son, ni me aparece donde crearmelas. ¿Que debo hacer?

Comment: Grave error. Nunca borres una carpeta a mano, cambiándola por otra. El proceso de instalación o actualización se encarga de eso. Si no tenías ninguna tabla, o si tienes copia de seguridad de tus bases de datos/tablas, recomendaría que desinstales, **usando el desinstalador** y que instales de nuevo desde cero. Otra opción sería recuperar tu carpeta borrada desde la papelera (renombrando antes la actual por otra cosa). Y una tercera opción sería probar con: usuario: `root`, password:`` (nada en el campo de password). Esta opción no creo que te sirva de mucho, no creo que veas las bd anteriores.

Comment: Vale, he recuperado de la papelera la anterior versión, pero ahora la cuestión es como actualizo sin que todo se me borre.

Comment: @MiguelAlparez Realizas un backup de las bases de datos, desinstalas, instalas la nueva versión y recuperas de los backup las bases de datos que necesitas.

Comment: Es decir, desinstalo y vuelvo a instalar... ¿No hay un modo de que se instale una actualización sin pasar por una desinstalación?

Answer (score 0):

Para actualizar phpmyadmin de manera manual,vaya a su carpeta phpMyAdmin actual. Si está utilizando XAMPP en su computadora local, por lo general, instala XAMPP en su disco duro principal.
Abre tu disco duro.
Abra su carpeta XAMPP. Verás tu carpeta phpMyAdmin:
Directorio phpmyadmin en xampp

Luego renombra tu carpeta phpMyAdmin, cambie el nombre de su carpeta phpMyAdmin a phpMyAdmin_old:

Nota: Este paso es opcional. Puede actualizar su phpMyAdmin simplemente reemplazando su antigua carpeta phpMyAdmin por una recién descargada.

Pero mantener las viejas carpetas y archivos de phyMyAdmin antes de ejecutar la actualización, solo para estar seguro, es una buena práctica.

De esta manera, si durante la actualización algo falla, o si arruina las cosas, siempre puede cambiar el nombre de la carpeta de phpMyAdmin_old a phpMyAdmin. Y estás de vuelta a una versión de phpMyAdmin en funcionamiento.

Copia tu archivo de configuración phpMyAdmin. Dentro de su directorio phpMyAdmin original, encuentre el archivo config.inc 
Haz una copia de eso.
Coloque el archivo copiado en su nuevo directorio phpMyAdmin .
Descarga la versión más reciente de phpMyAdmin
Vaya a phpmyadmin.net .
Descarga la versión más reciente de phpMyAdmin.
Extraiga los archivos en su disco duro:
Copie todos los archivos y carpetas extraídos en su nueva carpeta phpMyAdmin .

Probando la Nueva Versión
Ahora inicie su phpMyAdmin. Debes ver que se ha actualizado con éxito:
La versión de phpMyAdmin ya está actualizada

¡Felicidades! Acabas de aprender a actualizar tu versión de phpMyAdmin.